# How do I "Buy" tokens on the Rinkeby (test) environment?

Tags: ether, rinkeby

This is a noob question I presume. I just started with the Ethereum Wallet. No previous bitcoin experience. I have 0 ether. 
Can I start "playing" with the test environment ("Rinkeby" network as I understand). Do I need to buy ether for that?

Comment: December 2020: https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/getting-started/where-to-get-testnet-ether

Comment: How can i exchange rinkeby eth to eth main net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RinkedBy official faucet uses 3rd party social network to prevent malicious actors.

You only need [to go to this page](https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet) and for example tweet the following:

```
Requesting faucet funds into 0x***YOU_ADDRESS***************** on the #Rinkeby #Ethereum test network.
```

Then, copy-paste the link of you tweet into the faucet page and select the amount of ether you want. After a few seconds, you should receive the fund.

[image]

**More Info:**

> How does this work?
>
> This Ether faucet is running on the Rinkeby network. To prevent malicious actors from exhausting all available funds or accumulating enough Ether to mount long running spam attacks, requests are tied to common 3rd party social network accounts. Anyone having a Twitter, Google+ or Facebook account may request funds within the permitted limits.
>
> ```
> To request funds via Twitter, make a tweet with your Ethereum address pasted into the contents (surrounding text doesn't matter). Copy-paste the tweets URL into the above input box and fire away!
>
> To request funds via Google Plus, publish a new public post with your Ethereum address embedded into the content (surrounding text doesn't matter). Copy-paste the posts URL into the above input box and fire away!
>
> To request funds via Facebook, publish a new public post with your Ethereum address embedded into the content (surrounding text doesn't matter). Copy-paste the posts URL into the above input box and fire away!
> ```
>
> You can track the current pending requests below the input field to see how much you have to wait until your turn comes.
> The faucet is running invisible reCaptcha protection against bots.

Comment: Did not work for me. Might be buggy.

Comment: why is this so convoluted.

Comment: Works in Jan 2022.

Answer (score 4):

While the above answer of using https://faucet.rinkeby.io/ is the official answer, feel free to also try out http://rinkebyfaucet.com which doesn't require a social network address.

Comment: .................. dead

Comment: Thank you, this was the fastest way

Answer (score 2):

**step 1** : create below text with your address

```
Requesting faucet funds into 0x000000000000000000000000 on the #Rinkeby #Ethereum test network.
```

**step 2** : paste into this [twitter link](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Requesting%20faucet%20funds%20into%200x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000%20on%20the%20%23Rinkeby%20%23Ethereum%20test%20network.)
[image]

**step 3** : now view/open that tweet on your twitter account and copy such link from addressbar `https://twitter.com/vijay777pawar/status/1008949702232924160`
[image]

**step 4** : now paste this twitter link in https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet
[image]

**step 5** : and click on give me ether

**step 6** : check balance from https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/balancecheck-tool
[image]

If above document is not working then read this https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet

Comment: This always resolves to "No Etherum address found"

Answer (score 1):

Add a Ether from Rinkeby test Network:

Follow the steps for add a free test network - Ether to your wallet:

1. copy a address of your Wallet(Eather wallet/Metamask)
2. open this : http://rinkeby-faucet.com/
3. Add your address to this link.

And finally you get free Ether for your test Wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for the Rinkeby net you can get them here: https://faucet.rinkeby.io/

Comment: Please refer to the How does it work section of the page. You need to publish your address in a social media post to prevent spam.